# How to set bold text within spreadsheet cell using C# and LibreOffice/OpenOffice?

Tags: c#, libreoffice, openoffice-calc

I'm converting one of our in-house apps to use OpenOffice/LibreOffice as well as MsOffice.

In an Excel spreedsheet with C#/.NET it is fairly simple to set only parts of text within a cell to bold.  It looks like this:

```
sheet.Range["A1"].Characters[startIndex, length].Font.Bold = true;
```

How do you do the equivalent in OO/LO?

Answer (score 0):

Have you look at XML File format  ?
http://www.openoffice.org/xml/xml_specification.pdf

I am not sure about open Excel but in MS-Excel you can define the font and Append it .

```
var fonts = new Fonts();
            var font = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Font();
            var fontName = new FontName {Val = StringValue.FromString("Arial")};
            var fontSize = new FontSize {Val = DoubleValue.FromDouble(11)};
            font.FontName = fontName;
            font.FontSize = fontSize;
            fonts.Append(font);
            var cellFormats = new CellFormats();
                     cellFormats.Append(fonts);
```

Comment: That's not really what I am trying to do.  It is easy to apply formatting to the whole cell.  What I want to do is have a cell where the bold status changes within the cell.  Something like "This **word** is in bold."  You can do it manually, I just can't figure out how to code it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it, but it works.  The basic idea is to use the example code for inserting text into a cell and then create a cursor on the desired subrange and set the CharWeight property on the subrange.

```
var xCellText = (unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XText)cell;
var xTextCursor = xCellText.createTextCursor();
xCellText.insertString(xTextCursor, newLine, false);
xTextCursor.gotoStart(false);
xTextCursor.goRight((short)boldStartIndex, false);
xTextCursor.goRight((short)boldLength, true);
var xPropSet = (XPropertySet)xTextCursor;
xPropSet.setPropertyValue("CharWeight", new uno.Any(unoidl.com.sun.star.awt.FontWeight.BOLD));
```